# what is the correct way of setting a global variable in rundeck

Tags: rundeck

I have a Windows server running the community version of Rundeck and I am trying to set a global variable to use in my PowerShell scripts. So I edited the "framework.properties" file and set my variable.

[image]

I then created a test job (script) and tried to expand the variable, using all three methods shown in rundeck.

[image]

When I run the job I don't get any output though

[image]

So what is the correct way to set a global variable in rundeck?

Comment: Did you restart rundeck after editing the framwork.properties file? this is mandatory if you want to use "framework globals". Alternatively you can use globals in the project config file (whitout restarting Rundeck): project settings > edit configuration > edit configuration file and then add the global: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/config-file-reference.html#global-execution-variables. I tested on Windows successfully: https://imgur.com/Dhf5fFK

Comment: it seems to be able to expand the variable after restarting the rundeck service. Slight issue though, if I add more IP's in the same variable, and try to loop through them using foreach, it reads all the IP's as a single variable.

Comment: Let me add the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart the Rundeck service after editing the `framwork.properties` file.

This is mandatory if you want to use "framework globals". Alternatively, you can use globals in the project config file (without restarting Rundeck).

For that, go to project settings > edit configuration > edit configuration file and then add the [global](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/config-file-reference.html#global-execution-variables).

Check the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Su1wm.jpg) after restarting Rundeck.